# TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/ login.html

Tags: django, authentication, registration, logout

Imm trying to use default django login system. It gives me error that my login.html templates does not exist.

I have my login templates saved in a root directory..> templates>registration>login.html

Imm using custom user models and token authentication..

Here's what i tried ..>

## account urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path 


urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = "login.html"), name='login'),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

## Main App Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url

from articles.views import ArticleDetail, ArticleList
from account.views import AccountList

from rest_framework.authtoken import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('article/', ArticleList.as_view()),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', AccountList.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', include('account.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

## Templates dir in settings.py#

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Does using a custom user models and Token auth effects default login system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change the template_name and everything will work

```
template_name = "registration/login.html"
```

Comment: Mate one more question... Is it necessary to create User Login, Logout , Registration form when you want to use flutter app to Login or create user to database?

Comment: Yes, for that you have to authenticate your user using API for that you can not use Django built in login for that you can directly use Django rest framework authentication that will create token after the authentication and you can pass that token to validate use if you want to create a flutter app using Django as a backend so you have to also learn Django Rest Framework for convert data into json.